# want to run query on each database, How to calculate the performance difference in C# and in SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008

I am working on sql server monitoring product and i have database query that will fetch data regarding All Table details of all the Databases in SQL server.

For this i have two options.

1. Fire query on data base from code as `select name from [master].sys.sysdatabases`
   Get the DB name of all the data base first then i will fire my main query on each DB
   using `"USE <fetched DB name>;"+"mainQuery";`

   Please check followin code for the same.

   ```
   public DataTable GetResultsOfAllDB(string query)
   {
       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString);
       string locleQuery = "select name from [master].sys.sysdatabases";
       DataTable dtResult = new DataTable("Result");
       SqlCommand cmdData = new SqlCommand(locleQuery, con);
       cmdData.CommandTimeout = 0;

       SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdData);
       DataTable dtDataBases = new DataTable("DataBase");
       adapter.Fill(dtDataBases);

       foreach (DataRow drDB in dtDataBases.Rows)
       {
           if (dtResult.Rows.Count >= 15000)
               break;
           locleQuery = " Use [" + Convert.ToString(drDB[0]) + "]; " + query;
           cmdData = new SqlCommand(locleQuery, con);
           adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdData);
           DataTable dtTemp = new DataTable();
           adapter.Fill(dtTemp);
           dtResult.Merge(dtTemp);
       }
       return dtResult;
   }
   ```
2. I will use sys store procedure i.e.EXEC sp_MSforeachdb and fetched data will be stored store data in table datatype select  from temptable; Drop Table temptable.
   Check following query for the same

   `Declare @TableDetail table
   (
   field1 varchar(500),
   field2 int,
   field3 varchar(500),
   field4 varchar(500),
   field5 decimal(18,2),
   field6 decimal(18,2)
   )
   INSERT @TableDetail EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?]; QYERY/COMMAND FOR ALL DATABASE'
   Select
   field1,field2 ,field3 ,field4 ,field5,field6 FROM @TableDetail`

Note : In second option query takes time because if number of database and number of table are huge then this will wait until all database get finish.

Now my question is which is the good option from above two options and why? or any other solution for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you going to determine the difference in System and Network latency between each test, this could ultimately be the defining factor that has nothing to do with DB performance per say.

Comment: i am concern about the, is it ok to each time open connection for each DB and fetch data or only open one connection run huge query. and regarding N/W latency yes you are right this is nothing to do with DB performance but which is the better reopening connection for each DB or oly one connectopn

Comment: What did you end up doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One key difference is the second option blocks until everything is done.  All of the work is done sql server side.  That has the issue of not being able to apply feedback to the user as it runs and it can potentially time out and not be resiliant to network blips.  This option can be used as a pure sql script (some sql admins like that) where the first needs a program.

In the first example, the client is doing iterative more granular tasks where you can supply feedback to the user.  You can also retry in the face of network blips without redoing all of the work.  In the first example, you can also use SqlConnectionBuild instead of USE concatentation.

If performance is a concern, you could also potentially parallelize the first one with some locking around adapter.Fill

Answer (score 1):

Both suck - they are both serial.

Use the first, get rid of the ridiculous objects (DataSet) and use TASKS to parallelize X databases at the same time. X determined by trying ut how much load the server can handle.

Finished.

Comment: Yes you are right, but the problem is my app is in 2.0 its difficult to handle parallelism in 2.0. I have to apply Threading then and i dont want to do this because this product is Monitoring product i am not suppose to do such things .. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Ah - no, sorry. Use the ThreadPool, queue user work items. I have been doing that stuff since 1.0. No problem with that.

Answer (score 0):

If your queries are simple enough you can try to generate single script instead of execute queries in each DB one by one:

```
select 'DB1' as DB, Field1, Field2, ...
from [DB1]..[TableOrViewName]
union all
select 'DB2' as DB, Field1, Field2, ...
from [DB2]..[TableOrViewName]
union all
...
```

Answer (score -1):

Everything is looking fine. I just want to add **Using statements** for **IDisposable objects**

```
public DataTable GetResultsOfAllDB(string query)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString))
            {
                string locleQuery = "select name from [master].sys.sysdatabases";
                DataTable dtResult = new DataTable("Result");
                using (SqlCommand cmdData = new SqlCommand(locleQuery, con))
                {
                    cmdData.CommandTimeout = 0;

                    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdData))
                    {

                        using (DataTable dtDataBases = new DataTable("DataBase"))
                        {
                            adapter.Fill(dtDataBases);

                            foreach (DataRow drDB in dtDataBases.Rows)
                            {
                                if (dtResult.Rows.Count >= 15000)
                                    break;
                                locleQuery = " Use [" + Convert.ToString(drDB[0]) + "]; " + query;
                                cmdData = new SqlCommand(locleQuery, con);
                                adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdData);
                                using (DataTable dtTemp = new DataTable())
                                {
                                    adapter.Fill(dtTemp);
                                    dtResult.Merge(dtTemp);
                                }
                            }
                            return dtResult;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```